# Plotting Curves aligned to Dynamic Time Warping Matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have problems to plot two arrays with the right scaling. I use the dtw package to compare the two arrays, x and y (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dtw/1.0). The function dtw returns a matrix and a path.
With the following code, I can plot the matrix and the path:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dist, cost, acc, path = dtw(x, y, dist=lambda x, y: norm(x - y, ord=1))

plt.imshow(acc.T, origin='lower', cmap=cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.plot(path[0], path[1], 'w')

plt.ylim((-0.5, acc.shape[1]-0.5))
plt.xlim((-0.5, acc.shape[0]-0.5))
```

Resulting figure:
[image]
However, I would like to plot the two curves aligned to it, like shown in (http://www.psb.ugent.be/cbd/papers/gentxwarper/DTWalgorithm.htm). One curve is above the matrix, the other one is on the left side, so that you can compare which parts are equal.

Comment: Definitely do-able. [This example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html) has different data types, but a similar layout. Maybe you can adapt it?

Answer (score 3):

Like suggested by kwinkunks (see comment) I used [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html) as template. Please note that I used "plt.pcolor()" instead of "plt.image()" to plot the matrix. This is my code and the resulting figure:

```
'''
Plotting
'''

nullfmt = NullFormatter()

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.12, 0.60
bottom, height = 0.08, 0.60
bottom_h =  0.16 + width 
left_h = left + 0.27 
rect_plot = [left_h, bottom, width, height]
rect_x = [left_h, bottom_h, width, 0.2]
rect_y = [left, bottom, 0.2, height]

# start with a rectangular Figure
plt.figure(2, figsize=(8, 8))

axplot = plt.axes(rect_plot)
axx = plt.axes(rect_x)
axy = plt.axes(rect_y)

# Plot the matrix
axplot.pcolor(acc.T,cmap=cm.gray)
axplot.plot(path[0], path[1], 'w')

axplot.set_xlim((0, len(x)))
axplot.set_ylim((0, len(linear)))
axplot.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)

# Plot time serie horizontal
axx.plot(x,'.', color='k')
axx.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
xloc = plt.MaxNLocator(4)
x2Formatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')
axx.yaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)
axx.yaxis.set_major_formatter(x2Formatter)

# Plot time serie vertical
axy.plot(y,linear,'.',color='k')
axy.invert_xaxis()
yloc = plt.MaxNLocator(4)
xFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')
axy.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)
axy.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xFormatter)
axy.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)

#Limits
axx.set_xlim(axplot.get_xlim())
axy.set_ylim(axplot.get_ylim())

plt.show()
```

[image]